# Query results per month instead of a whole period

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

What I'm basically getting now is in a span of 6 months
   PATIENT - Number of events in 6 months
1
2
3
4
5

What i want to get is

PATIENT - Number of events in 1st month - ... 2nd month - ... 3rd month .. till 6th month
1
2
3
4
5

Which ofc the results are the same, only that they're divided by month instead all in one column

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PMP.TOP5BonosVencidos
(
    @pComienzo_Semestre datetime = null
)
AS
BEGIN

select TOP 5 PACIENTE_DOCUMENTO, PACIENTE_NOMBRE, PACIENTE_APELLIDO, COUNT(*)         
from PMP.BONO_FARMACIA, PMP.PACIENTE, PMP.COMPRA_BONO
where CAST(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO AS DATE) >= CAST(@pComienzo_Semestre AS DATE) AND
CAST(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO AS DATE) < DATEADD(month,6,CAST(@pComienzo_Semestre AS DATE)) AND
PMP.PACIENTE.PACIENTE_ID = COMPRA_BONO_PACIENTE_ID AND
COMPRA_BONO_CANTIDAD_FARMACIA > 0 AND
COMPRA_BONO_ID = COMPRA_BONO
group by PACIENTE_DOCUMENTO, PACIENTE_NOMBRE, PACIENTE_APELLIDO
order by COUNT(*) DESC
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add month to the grouping:

```
select TOP 5 PACIENTE_DOCUMENTO, PACIENTE_NOMBRE, PACIENTE_APELLIDO, DATEPART(Month, FECHA_VENCIMIENTO) as [Month], COUNT(*)         
from PMP.BONO_FARMACIA, PMP.PACIENTE, PMP.COMPRA_BONO
where CAST(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO AS DATE) >= CAST(@pComienzo_Semestre AS DATE) AND
CAST(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO AS DATE) < DATEADD(month,6,CAST(@pComienzo_Semestre AS DATE)) AND
PMP.PACIENTE.PACIENTE_ID = COMPRA_BONO_PACIENTE_ID AND
COMPRA_BONO_CANTIDAD_FARMACIA > 0 AND
COMPRA_BONO_ID = COMPRA_BONO
group by PACIENTE_DOCUMENTO, PACIENTE_NOMBRE, PACIENTE_APELLIDO, DATEPART(Month, FECHA_VENCIMIENTO)
```

I removed `ORDER BY` as I'm not sure what the ordering should be in this case - please add the relevant ordering yourself.